# Get value between <b> tag using regex in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I have searched up and down trying to find an answer that will work for me but haven't been able to figure this out. I'm using Yahoo Pipes for this.

```
Lake Harmony Estates <b>Sleeps: 16</b>
```

What I need to do is extract the `Sleeps: 16` out from the B tag and output just that value and nothing else. I don't suspect this is very hard to do, but given my limited regex knowledge it's giving me troubles. I've tried adapting regex code pertaining to other tags, but just can't seem to get this one to work.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
Here is my pipe if you wanted to take a look at the regex horrible-ness I've created. The one I'm trying to work though is the item.sleeps, last entry in the 2nd regex
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=567026d850223b0075d80fd3c9bf7e75

Comment: Which language are you trying this in?

Comment: This is Yahoo Pipes, I'm not sure there is a specific language. I've read it's similar to perl, but that isn't my area of knowledge per say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question to Twitter and got a response back that worked for me.

```
(?s)^.*<b>(.*?)</b>.*
```

Replace with $1 and have G flag checked.

This solution did everything I needed. I had additional data that I had already excluded in my example that became unnecessary with this regex.

Answer (score 0):

This should fit your needs assuming the html isn't ladened with quotes and such. Note that the `+` will mean that empty `<b>` tags are ignored. Also, html is not truly passable via regex, so this will only work for basic tags. It should work even if the tag has an ID or a class property, but there are absolutely manners to break this regex.

```
/<b[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/b>/
```

Comment: Tried it out, doesn't have any effect on it for some reason.

Comment: Do you know if it is using perl or posix regex?